# Count the number of times keywords appear in a mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have a database table in which i collect the keywords which people use to visit my website, all of these keywords are stored in the column string.

Now what i want to do is count the words and group them by the number of times they are used, so for example if marketing is used six times i want to output to a table Marketing 6.

My problem is not sure if there is a function that will allow mysql to count all of the instances of words and then add them up.

And if not is there a way this can be done?

Comment: This should give you some idea.. http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as i have understood your question, you are searching something like this:

`SELECT COUNT(*), KEYWORD FROM TABLE GROUP BY KEYWORD`

Comment: Hi thanks yes but i don't know what the keywords are, so i just need to group all words in the column string by the number of times entered.

Comment: In my statement `KEYWORD` is the name of the Column. If yours is `string` you can exchange KEYWORD by STRING.